# Trigger workflow when creating a release

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm attempting to create a GitHub Action which builds and pushes an image to Docker Hub.  Easy enough since there's already a standard workflow for that.  However, is there a way to have the action be triggered whenever I create a release for my repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by

```yaml
on:
  release:
    types: [published]
```

[Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release)